# Docker container connection refuse

Tags: angular, docker

I am new to docker and I am trying to containerize my angular application. I build docker image using command "docker build -t myngapp" and run container using command

```
docker run -it -p 3001:3001 myngapp
```

When I'm browsing the app I'm getting connection refuse error (http://localhost:3001/).

I follow different solutions from stack overflow unfortunately none of them worked.

```
FROM node:12.11.1-alpine
WORKDIR /ciopapp
COPY . ./
RUN npm install --force
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@9.1.1
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3001
CMD ["npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Are you sure, the backend started with `npm start` does listen to port 3001?

Answer (score 0):

Normally an Angular application **in serve mode** starts on port `4200`. I think I need to see your package.json with the start command.

Otherwise you can `build` your Angular application. But then you need to install a webserver (like `nginx`) in your container, too, like this:

**DOCKERFILE**

```
FROM node:latest AS build

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/dist/"yourAppName"/usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**NGINX CONFIG (as example)**

```
error_log /dev/stderr;
access_log /dev/stdout main;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    gzip                    on;
    gzip_comp_level         6;
    gzip_vary               on;
    gzip_min_length         1000;
    gzip_proxied            any;
    gzip_types              text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/javascript;
    gzip_buffers            16 8k;
    client_max_body_size    32M;

    location / {
      # First attempt to serve request as file, then
      # as directory, then redirect to index (Angular) if no file found.
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
      add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
    }
}
```

#### Back to your code

If you handle `serve` and got a connection refused error you can use the `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` parameter. The `host` help in newer Angular versions so solve the connection refused error.

#### Your updated code

```
FROM node:12.11.1-alpine
WORKDIR /ciopapp
COPY . ./
RUN npm install --force
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@9.1.1
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3001
["ng","serve","--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "3001"]
```

You can add this to your package.json, too:

#### Package.json

```
....
"scripts": {
   "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3001"
 } 
....
```

I ***remember** you again: You need to set the port 3001 explicitly. If you have problems after try my code, please show me the logs of your running docker container.

*Example*

```
$ docker run --name test -d busybox sh -c "while true; do $(echo date); sleep 1; done"
$ date
Tue 14 Nov 2017 16:40:00 CET
$ docker logs -f --until=2s test
Tue 14 Nov 2017 16:40:00 CET
Tue 14 Nov 2017 16:40:01 CET
Tue 14 Nov 2017 16:40:02 CET
```

Read more about docker logs [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/).

Have fun!